# how to increment a value using while loop python

Tags: python

could you tell me why my program doesnt increment "bot_points = 0"
"your_points = 0" to stop the while loop when some of these values reach 3

```
import random
rock_paper_scissors = ["ROCK", "PAPER", "SCISSORS"]


bot_points = 0
your_points = 0
while bot_points <= 3 or your_points <= 3:
    user_choice = input('type "rock", "paper" or "scissors":  ').upper()
    bot_choice = random.choice(rock_paper_scissors)
    if bot_choice == "ROCK" and user_choice == "ROCK":
        print("Draw")
    elif bot_choice == "ROCK" and user_choice == "PAPER":
        print("You win")
        your_points = your_points+1
    elif bot_choice == "PAPER" and user_choice == "PAPER":
        print("Draw")
    elif bot_choice == "PAPER" and user_choice == "SCISSORS":
        print("You win")
        your_points= your_points+1
    elif bot_choice == "PAPER" and user_choice == "ROCK":
        print("You lose")
        bot_points = bot_points+1
    elif bot_choice == "SCISSORS" and user_choice == "PAPER":
        print("You lose")
        bot_points = bot_points+1
    elif bot_choice == "SCISSORS" and user_choice == "ROCK":
        print("You win")
        your_points = your_points+1
    elif bot_choice == "SCISSORS" and user_choice == "SCISSORS":
        print("Draw")
    elif bot_choice == "ROCK" and user_choice == "SCISSORS":
        print("You lose")
        bot_points = bot_points+1
```

Comment: while bot_points < 3 and your_points < 3 maybe?

Comment: A good habit to get into is to learn how to use print debugging. If you had displayed the score at the end of every round you would have seen that the variables *were both*, in fact, incrementing properly, which would've probably very quickly helped you realize the problem was in your `while` loop condition.

Comment: I'd recommend also cutting down the draw conditions to `if bot_choice == user_choice`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two issues:

1. You test for `<= 3`, so it won't end until someone wins *four* times
2. You test `bot_points <= 3 or your_points <= 3`, so it won't end until *both* players win at least four times; `and` would end when either reaches the threshold

If you want to end when *either* player wins *three* times, change the test to:

```
while bot_points < 3 and your_points < 3:
```